# Subset Excel rows based on column values using vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a workbook:

```
sheet1:
id name ...(100 columns)
1  a
2  b
3  c
...
(about 300,000 rows)
sheet2:
id
3
4
...
(about 50,000 rows)
```

I want to select rows in sheet1 with id in sheet2, I tried using vlookup in sheet2:

```
VLOOKUP($A2, sheet1!$A:$CV, 1)
```

the problem is that I have 100 columns, autofill the cell horizontally doesn't automatically add the last parameter in vlookup, i.e., I have to manually change it to 2,3,...,100. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a helper row above your table with values `2, 3, 4, ... , 100`. Say it will be row 1 so your destination table shifts down one row.

Then your VLOOKUP formula is like this:

```
=VLOOKUP($A3,sheet1!$A:$CV,B$1,0)
```

So you can specify the resulting column for VLOOKUP dynamically! Voila!

Variant 2 (without helper row):

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,sheet1!$A:$CV,COLUMN(),0)
```

So as you see, `COLUMN()` function returns the number of column your formula is typed into.
**Note:** this formula will only work if you start writing it in destination table from column `2:2` on your worksheet. Otherwise you will need to apply offset like this (for example, if you start writing formula from column `5:5`):

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,sheet1!$A:$CV,COLUMN()-3,0)
```